# Get average value of each (Sub) column

Tags: tableau-api

i would like to calculate the average of values of each "main" column, as shown in the picture (named as bundling column). Each bundling(main) column has 1 to N "sub columns" (which are values for a certain datetime). The bundling itself is variable, it changes for different filters.

How can i reference to these sub columns to get the sum/count and average of these? I thought of using the "Window average" function but i don't have an idea how to define the start/end offset parameters. Not sure if window average is the correct option.

Thank you very much[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A level of detail (LOD) calculation will allow you to control at what level the aggregation occurs.

```
{INCLUDE [Agg(Bundling)]: AVG([Agg(Error Select)]}
```